# Java String.hashCode() implementation in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to imlplement String.hashCode() function in Bash. I Couldn't figure out the bug.

this is my sample implementation

```
function hashCode(){ #similar function to java String.hashCode()
foo=$1
echo $foo
h=0
for (( i=0; i<${#foo}; i++ )); do
    val=$(ord ${foo:$i:1})
    echo $val
    if ((31 * h + val > 2147483647)) 
    then
        h=$((-2147483648 + (31 * h + val) % 2147483648 ))

    elif ((31 * h + val < -2147483648))
    then
        h=$(( 2147483648 - ( 31 * h + val) % 2147483648 )) 
    else
        h=$(( 31 * h + val))
    fi
done
printf %d $h
}

function ord() { #asci to int conversion
    LC_CTYPE=C printf %d "'$1"
}
```

Java function looks like this

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Expected output for string "__INDEX_STAGING_DATA__0_1230ee6d-c37a-46cf-821c-55412f543fa6" is "1668783629" but the output is -148458597

Note - Have to handle java int overflow and underflow.

Comment: What is `ord` in `val=$(ord ${foo:$i:1})`?

Comment: I forgot to put that function, It is converting char to ascii value. Now edited

Comment: The h is initialized with `int h = hash;` - what is hash? What is value? String toCharArray()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vinujan, your code is working for the purpose of hashing a given string using the algorithm you have included. You do not need the `ord` function as you can cause the literal conversion to ASCII value with `printf -v val "%d" "'${foo:$i:1}"` (unless you need the `LC_CTYPE=C` for character set differences).

For example, with just minor tweaks to your code, it will hash the string "hello" properly:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hashCode() {
    local foo="$1"
    local -i h=0
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#foo}; i++)); do

        printf -v val "%d" "'${foo:$i:1}"  # val is ASCII val

        if ((31 * h + val > 2147483647))   # hash scheme
        then
            h=$((-2147483648 + (31 * h + val) % 2147483648 ))
        elif ((31 * h + val < -2147483648))
        then
            h=$(( 2147483648 - ( 31 * h + val) % 2147483648 )) 
        else
            h=$(( 31 * h + val))
        fi
    done
    printf "%d" $h    # final hashCode in decimal
}

hash=$(hashCode "$1")

printf "\nhashCode: 0x%02x (%d decimal)\n" $hash $hash
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash hashcode.sh hello

hashCode: 0x5e918d2 (99162322 decimal)
```

Where you look like you have problems is in the algorithm for hashing itself. For example a longer string like `password` will result in your scheme returning a negative 64-bit value that looks suspect, e.g.:

```
$ bash hashcode.sh password

hashCode: 0xffffffffb776462d (-1216985555 decimal)
```

This may be your intended hash, I have nothing to compare the algorithm against. Look things over, and if you still have problems, edit your question and describe exactly what problems/error/etc. you are getting when you run the script and add that output to your question.

---

**Edit of Hash Function for Better Behavior**

Without an algorithm to implement, the only thing I can do is to reformulate the algorithm you provided to be better behaved when the calculations exceed `INT_MAX/INT_MIN`. Looking at your existing algorithm, it appeared to make the problems worse as large numbers were encountered rather than smoothing the values to insure they remained within the bounds.

Frankly, it looked like you had omitted subtracting `INT_MIN` or adding `INT_MAX` to `h` before reducing the value `modulo 2147483648` when it exceeded/fell below those limits. (e.g. you forgot the parenthesis around the subtraction and addition) Simply adding that to the hash algorithm seemed to produce better behavior and your desired output.

I also save the result of your hash calculation in `hval`, so that it is not computed multiple times each loop, e.g.

```
function hashCode() {
    local foo="$1"
    local -i h=0
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#foo}; i++)); do

        printf -v val "%d" "'${foo:$i:1}"  # val is ASCII val

        hval=$((31 * h + val))

        if ((hval > 2147483647))   # hash scheme
        then
            h=$(( (hval - 2147483648) % 2147483648 ))
        elif ((hval < -2147483648))
        then
            h=$(( (hval + 2147483648) % 2147483648 ))
        else
            h=$(( hval ))
        fi
    done
    printf "%d" $h    # final hashCode in decimal
}
```

**New Values**

Note the hash for `"hello"` remains the same (as you would expect), but the value for `"password"` is now better behaved and returns what looks like would be expected, instead of some sign-extended 64-bit value. E.g.,

```
$ bash hashcode2.sh hello

hashCode: 0x5e918d2 (99162322 decimal)

$ bash hashcode2.sh password

hashCode: 0x4889ba9b (1216985755 decimal)
```

And note, it does produce your expected output:

```
$ bash hashcode2.sh "__INDEX_STAGING_DATA__0_1230ee6d-c37a-46cf-821c-55412f543fa6"

hashCode: 0x63779e0d (1668783629 decimal)
```

Let me know if that is more what you were attempting to do.

Comment: Hi David C. Rankin, thank you for your contribution. I have added my expected output and current output in question.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, so the problem is in your interpretation of the actual hash algorithm. Some of the swings from `INT_MAX` to `INT_MIN`, etc.. look like there may be problems with how they are signed. I'll have a bit of time tomorrow to look into it and hopefully we can get it figured out for you.

Comment: Thanks David for the solution. I was almost there. Thanks again. great help.

Comment: Yes you were. Very close. That just one of the forest-for-the-trees errors you could stare at for days. Two sets of eyes are always better than one in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

I got an lean solution:

```
hashCode() {
    o=$1
    h=0
    for j in $(seq 1 ${#o})
    do
        a=$((j-1))
        c=${o:$a:1}
        v=$(echo -n "$c" | od -d)
        i=${v:10:3}
        h=$((31 * $h + $i ))
        # echo -n a $a c $c i $i h $h
        h=$(( (2**31-1) & $h ))
        # echo -e "\t"$h
    done
    echo $h
}
```

which was wrong. :) The error was in my clever bitwise-ORing of `(2**31-1) ^ $h` a bitwise ANDing seems a bit wiser: `(2**31-1) & $h`

This might be condensed to:

```
hashCode() {
    o=$1
    h=0
    for j in $(seq 1 ${#o})
    do
        v=$(echo -n "${$o:$((j-1)):1}" | od -d)
        h=$(( (31 * $h + ${v:10:3}) & (2**31-1) ))
    done
    echo $h
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @user unknown. This looks short. :D